# javascript Onchange

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, onchange

I've two dropdown lists one for pick up location and other for drop off location. Options in both are

> Jersey Airport
>   
>  Jersey Harbour
>   
>  Jersey Hotel 
>   
>  Guernsey Airport 
>   
>  Guernsey Harbour
>   
>  Guernsey Hotel

When I select the pick up in Guernsey, when they went to the drop off, Jersey would not 
appear...

```
function test(val){
    alert(val);
    if(val == 'Jersey Airport' || val == 'Jersey Harbour' || val == 'Jersey Hotel'){                 
      //                  
    }else if(val == 'Guernsey Airport' || val == 'Guernsey Harbour' || val == 'Guernsey Hotel'){                    
        //                    
    }else{

    }
}
```

How to do it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot of information to go on here, would have been nice to see you html for the selects.

However one thing i noticed is your if and else if are identical, were your intentions to do something like:

```
function test(val){
     alert(val);
     if(val == 'Jersey Airport' || val == 'Jersey Harbour' || val == 'Jersey Hotel'){
          //                  
     }else if(val == 'Guernsey Airport' || val == 'Guernsey Harbour' || val == 'Guernsey Hotel'){
          //                    
     }else{
          //
     }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok.I know... But i want to know which code can I use in if , else if and else

Comment: Please post more of your code, the HTML and the javascript that runs this function.